# Need Default password of Cisco dpr2320r2 router

Tags: router, passwords, wireless-router, password-recovery

My wifi password got autoreset, so I tried to connect the router using lan cable. Although I am not able to get into the router setting, probably the default password got reset too. So I tried resetting the router to factory setting using the hardware button. But still none of the passwords are working.

How can I know its password or reset it? The default is username - (blank), password - admin.
But still can't get into the setting.

Comment: the other way around makes more sense.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't get it. Which other way?

Comment: admin as a username and a blank password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't reset it properly. I have to press the reset button(the one in the hole), and keep holding it till all lights gets turned off and turn on again. It gets reset and then the username and password both becomes blank. I just need to hit enter :-D